# Div CSS3 Transform - Iphone

Tags: css, transform

I have a problem with a website. I use CSS3 and Transform to rotate the DIV. No problems on all browsers except Iphone and only on the FAQ page, the DIV will not turn!

http://www.bagolf.com/faq

Do you know why I searched for hours, and I do not understand.

```
<div class="block1_faq_container">
<div class="block1_faq_card">
<div class="front blue">
<h4 class="title">How many clubs may I put in a Bagolf bag?</h4>
</div>
<div class="back face center blue">
<span class="title-148-1-2">There are 15 dividers for 14 clubs and 1 umbrella. Each club has its own divider!</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS code :

```
.block1_faq_container{margin: 10px 0 0; width: 306px; height: 148px; text-   align:center;float:left;}
.block1_faq_card,
.block1_faq_card > div{width: inherit;height: inherit;transition: transform 1s; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}
.block1_faq_card > div{line-height: 148px;position: absolute;backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}
.block1_faq_container:hover .front{transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg); -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);}
.block1_faq_container:hover .back{transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(360deg); -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(360deg);}
.title {font-size: 1.9em !important;font-weight: lighter;color:#fff; vertical-align:middle;line-height:1.2em;display:inline-block; padding:10px; }
.title-148-1-2 {font-size: 1.4em !important;font-weight: normal;color:#fff; vertical-align:middle;line-height:1.2em;display:inline-block;padding:10px;}
.front.blue{background-color:#00a0e9;transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg); -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);line-height:148px;}
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the relevant CSS here

Comment: cool effect but its not the most pleasant user experience. if they are at your faq page, they want to find the answer to their question. usability is much more important than asthetics imo

Comment: also, hover events are useless in phones

Comment: Thank for response, but in Iphone no problem in this page also code it's the same : http://www.bagolf.com/gcart

Comment: What @ChrisM wanted to tell you is that users usually want to find their answer quickly and they don't care how it looks. This flipping card layout is useless, especially on mobile devices. So if you really insist on using them, at least make different design for mobile, where you should avoid hiding the data away from user. I'd recommend going with standard Q/A text only page, there's no use in reinventing the wheel. Also, this probably won't work on older browsers.

Comment: Also, when i first visited the page, I didn't even know the answers were behind the cards because the rotate is too slow.  when I first started to scan the page with my mouse, each card would only move slightly and then move back when the mouse continued on.  you have to leave the mouse there for like a full second for the answer to appear. at least make the rotate much quicker and maybe even make it so it stays on the answer even after the mouse moves off it and only goes back to the question with another hover or click event. just a suggestion

Comment: Yes I know it is not very comfortable but it is a request of my client who wants it. 

Look, on this page, it's good, it works on iPhone : http://www.bagolf.fr/gbag